# How to move UWP app location in Hololens2?

Tags: hololens

I want to make my UWP app always follow user in Hololens2 just like user interface,but I can not find any api can do it.

Is this even possible in UWP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 2D view UWP app, there is not an API that can move the App window. However, you can select the *Follow me* button in the top right corner of the app window (next to the Close button) to ask an app to start or stop following you. This way without any code, but some UI hints may be needed to guide the user.

Comment: I've got it.Thank for your answer!